# mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli; mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: mysqli, undefined, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm getting these errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: link in login.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,
>   null given in login.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: link in login.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in login.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given
>   in login.php on line 19

Here's the code:

```
<?php

session_start();


$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(); 
mysqli_select_db($link,'lr') or die();  


function sanitize($data) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $data);     <<line 11
}



function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);    
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username'");        <<line 18
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) ==1) ? true : false;        <<line19

}


if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password';    

    } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {  
        $errors[] = 'User not found';
        }


}

?>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are “undefined variable” errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use $_GLOBALS['link'] inside function.

Like this:

```
    function sanitize($data) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($_GLOBALS['$link'], $data);     <<line 11
}
```

Same thing inside user_exist function.

Answer (score 0):

Global may have worked to fix the problem, but it's better to pass the variable into the function.

```
function sanitize($data, $A) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($A, $data);     <<line 11
}
function user_exists($username, $A) {
    $username = sanitize($username);    
    $query = mysqli_query($A, "SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'usernam' = '$username'");        <<line 18
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) ==1) ? true : false;        <<line19

}

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username, $link) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password';    

    } else if (user_exists($username, $link) === false) {  
        $errors[] = 'User not found';
        }


}
```